# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'csv'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export the user details from the auth_user table to a CSV file in the `Django admin panel`. I have written the export to CSV function correctly and it has worked fine with other tables of mine. I have also provided the function location in urls.py correctly as:

```
(r'^auth/user//csv/', 'catalyst_db.catalyst.utils.admin_user_export'),
```

But Django has provided me the error saying that:

> ValueError at /auth/user/csv/  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'csv'

Any ideas to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a previous URL in your urlconf which is matching the CSV value before it gets to that pattern.

Comment: can u explain it further more with a little example

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a date(`User` model has a join date field) inside the csv file that you are trying to upload.The date field may be corrupt,most probably contains an aphotrophe before the date entry.(You can see the aphostrophe in the formula bar).

This can be fixed by the find and replace of your spreadsheet application.

Replace `^.` with `&` in regular expression mode.